# Null Object Reference on Intent with Arraylist<Hashmap>

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I've got a Problem passing my Arraylist to the next Activity.
Here is my Error Code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

By my understanding, i am trying to get an Arraylist, which does not exist.
I made sure the Arraylist is filled and my Intend values are correct, but im still getting the Error.

Creating the Arraylist

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> names = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Creating the intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
            intent.putExtra("names", names);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Getting the intent

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usernamen = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) intent.getSerializableExtra("names");
```

As said, the Arraylist get's filled correctly via

```
name = new HashMap<String, String>();
    name.put("Name", spielername.getText().toString());
    name.put("Gender", gender.getText().toString());
    names.add(name);
```

If someone needs more information, i'll be happy to provide them.

Edit:

```
gobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(names.size() < 2){
                Toast.makeText(Spieler.this, "No Informations", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Spieler.this, Games.class);
            intent.putExtra("level", level.getProgress());
            intent.putExtra("names", names);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

The Button is sending me to the second Activity, so the Array has to be filled.

Comment: You are re declaring your ```intent``` here ```Intent intent = getIntent();```, should you not use your previously declared intent? Or make sure your ```getIntent()``` method returns an ```intent```, maybe it is returning null. Use debugger and check if ```getIntent()```'s return is not null.

Comment: maybe that `intent` in another `Activity` is empty?
thus `getSerializableExtra("names")` this method is called on `null` reference?

Comment: Could you show the code you used in the other activity?

Comment: Well, the first Activity is basically there. I've got two Edittext and the Intent in a Button.
The Array is correctly filling, i've checked that via a simple Toast.

Comment: `Intent intent = getIntent();` in Game Activity is different from null?

Comment: @Specializedx3, send and receive data with `Serializable`

Comment: Its not null, i've just implemented
`if (intent != null)
            usernamen = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("names");
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Intent is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

The Error still occurs.

Comment: is it `namen` or `names` ?? 
`intent.putExtra("namen", namen);`

Comment: have you try: `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("names", namen);
intent.putExtras(bundle);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> names = new ArrayList<>();

 HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

 map.put("Name", "Spieler");

 map.put("Gender", "male");

 names.add(map);
```

**Send the data with Intent**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putSerializable("keyName",names);

Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);

i.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(i);
```

**Get the data from Intent**

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();

Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

Log.e("SecondActivity","yourArrayList--"+(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>)bundle.getSerializable("keyName"));
```

Comment: @Specializedx3, Mark this correct answer and upvote it so that It will help other users as well. Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the value first, with either using Bundle:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putSerializable("names", namen); 
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

or casting the list with Serializable:

```
intent.putExtra("names", (Serializable) names);
```